# Spring microservice registered but getting UnknownHostException

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, microservices, resttemplate

I've got an issue with calling my microservice.

I run the server, and my microservice registers correctly:

[image]

But when I try and call a method in microservice, it fails with `UnknownHostException`.

This is how my `RestTemplate` and `MsImageService` beans are made:

```
@Configuration
@EnableAsync
@EnableGlobalMethodSecurity(prePostEnabled = true)
public class MvcConfig extends WebMvcConfigurerAdapter {

    @Bean
    @LoadBalanced
    public RestTemplate restTemplate() {
            return new RestTemplate();
    }

    @Bean
    public MsImageService msImageService() {
            return new MsImageService("http://IMAGES-MICROSERVICE");
    }
}
```

And this is how I autowire it in my service:

```
@Autowired
@LoadBalanced
private RestTemplate restTemplate;
```

These are the properties I use on my **server**:

```
server.port=8761

spring.thymeleaf.enabled=false

eureka.instance.hostname=localhost
eureka.client.register-with-eureka=false
eureka.client.fetch-registry=false
eureka.client.service-url.default-zone=http://${eureka.instance.hostname}:${server.port}/eureka/

logging.level.com.netflix.eureka=INFO
logging.level.com.netflix.discovery=INFO
```

And this is the properties in my **service**:

```
spring.application.name=images-microservice
spring.freemarker.enabled=false
spring.thymeleaf.enabled=false
security.basic.enabled=false
eureka.instance.instance-id=${spring.application.name}
eureka.client.service-url.default-zone=http://localhost:8761/eureka/
server.port=2222
logging.level.com.netflix.eureka=INFO
logging.level.com.netflix.discovery=INFO
```

Any help is appreciated!

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

From your **server** properties, try to remove the below line. It makes eureka client inside your server not fetch other servers info from eureka server.

```
eureka.client.fetch-registry=false
```

Also check that your Application class of server has `@EanbleEurekaClient` or `@EnableDiscoveryClient` annotation. Your server application also must be a Eureka client to fetch others.

From your **service** properties, remove the below line. Overriding instance-id is not required at all (but, it might not be related to your problem)

```
eureka.instance.instance-id=${spring.application.name}
```

If you need a full example, try to check this [example](https://github.com/yongsungyoon/spring-cloud-workshop) code. (Readme.md is written in Korean, but codes are very simple. So there will be no problem to read the code without readme)

Comment: Nope, I get the same `UnknownHostException` with those settings as well :(

Comment: Could you try to add `eureka.instance.prefer-ip-address=true` to your service properties ?

Comment: I can access it over the IP, but shouldn't I be able to access it over `spring.application.name` as well. That's how it worked before at least... It looks like my `@LoadBalanced` RestTemplate isn't being loaded? I dunno.. (`eureka.instance.prefer-ip-address=true` made no change to hostname, I can still access over IP though)